# Glade 'Parentless' Widget

Tags: ruby, gtk, glade

Is there a way to create 'parentless' widgets in Glade? What I mean is, for example, a table with no associated parent, so that I can assign it as a child of something else later.

What I'm trying to do is a GTK window with a 3 positions VBox, 2 of which will be static and 1 which will be dynamic. In this dynamic position I want to load a pre-defined table which will vary according to whatever I did in the static parts, like pressing X or Y buttons.

Is this possible, or do I have to create the dynamic table by code?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Gtk2, and Glade3. Thanks.

Edit: I tried creating a separate window with the tables and loading one of these tables into the intended window. I got an error, apparently a Child-Parent missmatch: "Gtk-CRITICAL **:gtk_box_pack: assertion `child->parent == NULL' failed"

Comment: For the separate window workaround: you need to either use `gtk_widget_reparent()` or manually a) take a reference to the child, b) remove it from temporary container, c) add it to intended container, d) unreference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you right-click on a widget in the widget palette, there is a menu item called something like "Add as toplevel widget" -- I don't have a copy of Glade handy right now to test what the name was exactly.

Then when you load your GtkBuilder file, the widget will be created without a parent, but the `GtkBuilder` will hold a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. I ended up doing it by code, but now I know for future reference.